# Flatness on the affine line for a coherent sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A:=\mathbb{C}[t], M$ a finitely generated $A$ module. Denote by $m_\alpha$ the maximal ideal generated by $t-\alpha$ for $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$, $S_\alpha$ the multiplicative set which is the complement of $m_\alpha$, $A_\alpha$ the local ring $S_\alpha^{-1}A$ and  $M_\alpha$ the localized module $S_\alpha^{-1}M$. Suppose for some $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$, $\mathrm{Tor}^1_{A_\alpha}(M_\alpha,\mathbb{C})=0$. Does it imply that $\mathrm{Tor}^1_{A_\beta}(M_\beta,\mathbb{C})=0$ for any $\beta \in \mathbb{C}$?

**EDIT** Assume further that the coherent sheaf associated to $M$ is supported on the whole of the affine line $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ (by support I mean the definition mentioned in Hartshorne Ex. II.$5.6$)

Comment: Why do you think that this is true? Have you looked at a single example? Try $M = \mathbb{C}[t]/(f)$ for some polynomial $f$.

Comment: @Brandenburg: I am sorry for the mistake. I have edited the question. Do you have a counterexample to the question in the current form?

Comment: @user54369 Nothing to apologize for, but still not true: take something like the trivial line bundle and throw in some junk at a few points (so $M = \mathbb{C}[t] \oplus \mathbb{C}[t]/t$, say) - then at every point except the origin, $M$ looks nice and free, but at the origin it's all messed up.

Comment: @uncookedfalcon: Thanks a lot.